# Dataframe Format (background color of cells, Fonts, Font Size etc.)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a CSV file and I have converted this CSV file to Excel via pandas and also plotted some graph on the Excel sheet.

Now, I want to color some cells let's say B2: B6 grey color. I am unable to find solution to format these cells in dataframe.

I tried to use:

```
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['sheet1']

cellColor = workbook.add_format({'fg_color': '#808080'})

worksheet.set_column('B', None, cellColor)
```

It will set the whole column B with grey color while I just want to set 6 cells of column B.

If I use the following command it overwrites the cells with the red color and text disappear as well.

```
worksheet.write('L2', None, cellColor)
```

Comment: I am unable to find the solution of it. I tried some of the solutions mentioned but didn't work. Moreover, i couldn't find a question asking to color some cells with .set_column method. If i missed anything, please share the link. Thank you

Comment: Thank you let me look into the answer

Comment: I have tried the solution but it didn't work for me. It does not give me error but do not highlight any column. 

I also can't add comment on that thread due to reputation issue. What should i do now ? thank you